Find my family (of functions)! What family of functions best fits this evolution seen here?
I'll keep the question simple, and then add more context for those curious below. Does this gif remind you of the evolution of any specific family of functions? You can ignore the rebounding effects that occur later in the gif for x values greater than 1.5.

Added Context This is the plot of a curvature calculation for a series of simulations. These curvature calculations are made from a polynomial fit to data.This explains the artifacts we see creeping in later in the gif for larger x values, however the fit is most important for x-values up to 1.5. I was hoping to be able to describe this curvature behavior as an arhcetype I could deconvolve from observations of other data.
Are there any analytical detectives out there that can help me find my family :) ?

Can’t say for sure, but looks like the bell curve for $x<0.5$

It could be a bell curve whose center is moving asymptotically closer to that apparent limit near one, and with decreasing variance. Perhaps the early iterations just have the "center" of the bell curve over an unsupported region of the domain? But I feel like there is still a better family out there, this feels more asymmetric and heavy tailed to me. But thanks for providing the first "suspect" to the list :)
